# How to get the csrf_token in python(Django)

Tags: javascript, python, django, cordova

I want to build a cordova application and i want to use forms(django backend) on the application.

My question is how to get the csrf_token in python so i can serialize it and send it to javascript?

Any help will be apreciated.
Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? the docs have a pretty good section on `csrf_tokens`..

Comment: Use the cookie csrfcookie as show in the docs. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just got the correct answer .. thanks everybody for helping.

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template.context_processors import csrf

def my_view(request):
    csrf = unicode(csrf(request)['csrf_token'])
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSRF token is present in the template rendering context under `{{ csrf_token }}`. If you inline the Javascript in a template, you can render it.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript">
var csrfToken = "{{ csrf_token }}";
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Alternative is to access the cookie from javascript (credits Sergio Garcia). The how-to is in his link.

Comment: Actually the django docs show that the csrf_token is included in a cookie. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax

Comment: @SergioGarcia - There are more than one way to get the csrf_token, the template tag shown here *is* one of them.

Comment: Yes, but not the recommended one. If he is going to use it on JS, after the first ajax request your solution will became wrong. Using the cookie still  get the correct token.

Comment: after the first ajax call i get the csrf_token in the cookie ? Is not a better idea :when an ajax call is made , respond to the ajax call with the token you get in python?

Comment: Is a Cordova application (mobile application). Has nothing to do with django templating. I use django only for the backend and database. I connect with django using ajax calls.